# Comparing min and max estimates

Tags: hypothesis-testing, extreme-value

What is the most appropriate way to compare two groups of data in which, rather than a single value for each observation, we have two values per subject - a minimum and maximum value?

Basically, one group of observations is a control group and one group of observations comes from subjects that undergo a treatment producing a change in the parameter of interest. While it is not possible to measure the 'exact' value of this parameter, we can determine in each subject the limits of the interval in which the 'real' value is likely to be found. We thus find ourselves with two values (and only two values) per subject - a min and a max. Is there an appropriate statistical analysis to compare these two groups?  ​

EDIT:
@kjetil b halvorsen Thanks for the pointer - it's always a case of knowing the appropriate terminology... I'll look at "interval-valued data".

As to the data , it’s interval data in the sense that there are two possible methods for determining the value of the parameter – one is known to provide a minimum estimate (lower bound) and one a maximum estimate (upper bound). As to the specifics of the data a typical set might look like this:

`Min  Max Group
0.35 0.49     1
0.30 0.66     1
0.44 0.63     1
0.16 0.55     1
0.17 0.40     1
0.40 0.59     1
0.00 0.40     1
0.02 0.34     1
0.17 0.64     1
0.80 1.02     2
0.73 1.01     2
0.90 1.10     2
0.60 0.81     2
0.80 0.98     2
0.60 0.64     2
1.08 1.21     2
0.45 0.65     2
0.51 0.60     2
0.41 0.51     2`

Comment: Can you say some more about the data? Whar are typical values of $\text{max}-\text{min}$?  Are that difference very variable (compared to variation between subjects?)  How do you do the measurement, why can you only observe an interval?

Comment: You can also google with "interval-valued data"